# Tracking when the page-curl modal closes(is dismissed)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a page-curl modal working. But I need to be able to track when the user hits the page curl to close the page so I can see some vars. Is there an event I can listen for or some delegate where I will get a call to tell me of this event?

Many Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll see a lot of advice around here advocating the use of `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with a small delay to take action after the dismissal of modal views, but I think there may be a better approach.

Generate the notification yourself. If you control the view that's being presented modally, use the `viewDidDisappear:` method in its controller to generate an "I was dismissed" notification which you then subscribe to in your main view controller (or somewhere else). `viewDidDisappear:` is called after the page uncurl animation completes upon dismissal of the modal view.

In the worst case, where the view may be presented modally or otherwise, you can keep state on the presenting view controller to ensure that the notification actually corresponds to a modal view dismissal.

For completeness' sake, `viewWillDisappear:` is generated when the page decurl transition *starts*.