# Objective-C - Detect dismiss of a view after page curl

Tags: objective-c, dismiss, page-curl

I have a Main View which call a settings panel in another view with the page curl transition. All seems fine, but when I close the settings view it doesn't trigger the "viewWillAppear" method of my Main View causing me a lot of troubles because it doesn't get updated with the settings.

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156667/tracking-when-the-page-curl-modal-closesis-dismissed) which seems fine for me, but I don't know how to implement it. There is another easy way or someone who can explain to me how to apply that answer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reacting to views, you should probably react to settings changes. What I mean by that is that it would be a more solid design to use [Key-Value Observing (KVO)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) so that your main view can be notified of changes to the objects that represent your settings.

Alternatively, if you can't or don't want to observe a specific object, you can use `NSNotificationCenter` and have your settings view fire a notification when the new settings are applied and your other view can register to listen to those notifications.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/how-to-send-and-receive-message-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c) is a simple example of that.

I hope this helps solve your problem.